# how to free up memory occupied by parallelized processes

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

as shown in the below code, the iterable `self.__listOfKeyCellsCollector` contains hundereds of thousands of objects of type `KeyGridCellsInTreatmentFilterator`. each object or item in `self.__listOfKeyCellsCollector` is to be processed separately on a different
process by invoking the `run()` respectively.

the problem i am facing is, as the time of processing the objects in `self.__listOfKeyCellsCollector` elapse, the memory occupied is getting larger and larger, thus, despite the code is parallelized the os can not create more processes because memory occupied
is almost full

i would like to receive some suggesttions how to solve such situation please

**code**:

```
with Pool(processes=int(config['MULTIPROCESSING']['proceses_count'])) as KeyGridCellsInTreatmentFilterator.pool:
        for res in KeyGridCellsInTreatmentFilterator.pool.map(func=self.run,iterable=self.__listOfKeyCellsCollector,chunksize=self.__chunckSize):
                            
            fourCornersOfKeyWindows.append(res[0])
            areasOfCoverage.append(res[1])
            areasOfCoverage2.append(res[1])
            interception.append(res[2])
            
            centerPointsInWindowInImageCoordinate.append(res[3])
            centerPointsOfWindowInEPSG3857.append(res[4]) #equal to centerPointsOfKeyWindowInCRSInEPSG25832. they are the same
            centerPointsOfWindowInEPSG4326.append(res[5])
            pixelValuesOfCenterPoints.append(res[6])                    
            centerPointsOfWindowsAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326.append(res[7])
            """pixel values satisfy threshold value in key windows representative to treatment"""
            pixelsValuesSatisfyThreshold.append(res[8])#should be equal to pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInTIFFImageDataset
            """average heights of key windows representative to treatment"""
            averageHeights.append(res[9])
            """save distances"""
            distanceFromCenterPointOfKeyWindows.append(res[10])
            PECTerrestrialRisk.append(res[11])
            ETRForPECTerrestrial.append(res[12])
            
            if res[20] is not None:
                veryLowRiskForPECT+=res[20].veryLowRiskForPECTerrestrialAsString()
                lowRiskForPEC+=res[20].lowRiskForPECTerrestrialAsString()
                mediumRiskForPEC+=res[20].mediumRiskForPECTerrestrialAsString()
                highRiskForPEC+=res[20].highRiskForPECTerrestrialAsString()
            
            self.__inputStringToCopyFromStatement+="{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\t{8}\t{9}\t{10}\t{11}\t{12}\t{13}\t{14}\t{15}\t{16}\t{17}\t{18}\t{19}\t{20}\t{21}\t{22}\t{23}\t{24}\t{25}\t{26}\t{27}\t{28}\n".format(
            str(DateTimeUtils.getTimeToMacroSecondsPercision()),
            str(True),
            str(True),
            str(False),
            str(json.dumps(res[0]['features'][0]['geometry'])),
            str(""),
            str(res[10]),
            str(config['DEFAULT']['distance']),
            str(res[1]),
            str(config['DEFAULT']['area_of_coverage']),
            str(res[9]),
            str(config['DEFAULT']['average_height']),
            str(res[2]),
            str(config['DEFAULT']['interception']),
            str(res[13]),
            str(res[14]),
            str(res[15]),
            str(res[16]),
            str(res[17]),
            str(res[18]),
            str(res[19]),
            str(config['DEFAULT']['empty_polygon']),
            str(config['DEFAULT']['empty_polygon']),
            str(NumpyUtils.convertToNumpyArray(res[8][0])),
            str(config['DEFAULT']['pixelValue']),
            str(res[7]),
            str(config['DEFAULT']['empty_string']),
            str(res[6]),
            str(config['DEFAULT']['pixelValue']),
            )
           
    KeyGridCellsInTreatmentFilterator.pool.join()
```

**run**:

```
 def run(self,params:CellsInTreatmentInfoCollector):
    PECTerrestrialRiskForKeyGridCellsInTreatment = []
    ETRForPECTerrestrialForKeyGridCellsInTreatment = []
    if params is not None:
        logger.info(f"None-Zero covering cells filteration/separation phase:cell filtered as belongs to treatment:{params.getAreasOfCoveragePerWindow()}")
        fourCornersOfKeyWindowsAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326 = params.getFourCornersOfWindowsAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326()
        areasOfCoveragePerKeyWindow= params.getAreasOfCoveragePerWindow()
        interceptionPerKeyWindow= params.getInterceptionPerWindow()
        selectedSiteID = params.getSelectedSiteID()
        fieldCoordinatesAsTextInWKTInEPSG4326 = params.getTreatmentGeometry()
        threshold = params.getThreshold()
        visOp0 = params.getIsVisualizeAreaOfCoverage()
        visOp1 = params.getIsVisualizeAverageHeights()
        visOp2 = params.getIsVisualizeInterception()
        visOp3 = params.getIsVisualizeEndangeredAreas()
        centerPointsInKeyWindowInImageCoordinateSystem = params.getCenterPointsOfWindowInImageCoordinateSystem()
        centerPointsOfKeyWindowInEPSG3857 = params.getCenterPointsOfWindowInEPSG3857()
        centerPointsOfKeyWindowInEPSG4326 = params.getCenterPointsOfWindowInEPSG4326()
        pixelValuesOfCenterPointsOfKeyWindow = params.getPixelValuesOfCenterPointsOfWindow()
        centerPointsOfKeyWindowsAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326 = params.getCenterPointsOfWindowsAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326()
        pixelsValuesSatisfyThreshold = params.getPixelsValuesSatisfactionToThreshold()
        averageHeightsPerKeyWindow = params.getAverageHeightsPerWindow()
        distancesFromCenterPointsOfKeyWindowsToNearestEdge = params.getDistancesFromCenterPointsOfWindowsToNearestEdge()
        # _ETRRisk:ETRRisk = cellsInTreatmentInfoCollector.getETRRiskObject()
        
        iEnvironmentalRiskParams = params.getIEnvironmentaRiskParamskObject()
        data = params.getDataObject()
        # the following if-statement is only for debugging purposes
        if((config['KEYS_OF_ETR_RISK_CALC']['enableCalcAndPopulateETRRiskTablesInAWANTIVer2WS'] in data) and (data[config['KEYS_OF_ETR_RISK_CALC']['enableCalcAndPopulateETRRiskTablesInAWANTIVer2WS']] == True)):
            AR = params.getApplicationRate()
        
        _ETRRisk = None
        if((config['KEYS_OF_ETR_RISK_CALC']['enableCalcAndPopulateETRRiskTablesInAWANTIVer2WS'] in data) and (data[config['KEYS_OF_ETR_RISK_CALC']['enableCalcAndPopulateETRRiskTablesInAWANTIVer2WS']] == True)):
            """PECTerrestrialRisk for key-grid-cells in treatment"""
            numeratorPECTerrestrialRiskForKeyGridCellsInTreatment = (float(AR) * float(1 - (interceptionPerKeyWindow/100))) * float(config['ENVIRONMENTAL_RISK']['correctionFactor'])                               
            denumeratorPECTerrestrialRiskForKeyGridCellsInTreatment = float(config['ENVIRONMENTAL_RISK']['assumedDepth']) * (float(config['ENVIRONMENTAL_RISK']['soilDensityInKiloGrams']) * 1000000)
            PECTerrestrialRiskForKeyGridCellsInTreatment.append(numeratorPECTerrestrialRiskForKeyGridCellsInTreatment/denumeratorPECTerrestrialRiskForKeyGridCellsInTreatment)   
            """ETR for PECTerrestrial for key grid-cell in treatment"""
            ETRValueForPECTerrestrialForKeyGridCellsInTreatment = (numeratorPECTerrestrialRiskForKeyGridCellsInTreatment/denumeratorPECTerrestrialRiskForKeyGridCellsInTreatment) / float(config['ENVIRONMENTAL_RISK']['EC50EWCO'])
            ETRForPECTerrestrialForKeyGridCellsInTreatment.append( ETRValueForPECTerrestrialForKeyGridCellsInTreatment )            
            """ categorizing ETR-value to corresponding risk-category for PECTerrestrial """
            insecticideSelected = iEnvironmentalRiskParams[config['KEYS_OF_INSECTICIDES_PARAMS']['insecticideSelected']]
            dose = iEnvironmentalRiskParams[config['KEYS_OF_INSECTICIDES_PARAMS']['dose']]
            doseUnit = iEnvironmentalRiskParams[config['KEYS_OF_INSECTICIDES_PARAMS']['doseUnit']]
            dateOfSpray = iEnvironmentalRiskParams[config['KEYS_OF_INSECTICIDES_PARAMS']['dateOfSpray']]
            _ETRRisk = ETRRisk()
            _ETRRisk.categorizeETRFor(
                selectedSiteID=selectedSiteID,
                ETRValue=ETRValueForPECTerrestrialForKeyGridCellsInTreatment,  
                insecticideType=insecticideSelected,
                dose=dose,
                doseUnit=doseUnit,
                dateOfSpray=dateOfSpray,
                isForPECTerrestrial=True,
                isForPECDrift=False,
                isKey=True,
                fourCornersOfWindowCorrespondsToETRValueInEPSG4326=fourCornersOfKeyWindowsAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326['features'][0]['geometry'],
                geometryOfFourCornersOfWindowCorrespondsToETRValueInEPSG4326=config['DEFAULT']['empty_polygon'])
        
        return fourCornersOfKeyWindowsAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326,areasOfCoveragePerKeyWindow,interceptionPerKeyWindow,centerPointsInKeyWindowInImageCoordinateSystem,centerPointsOfKeyWindowInEPSG3857,centerPointsOfKeyWindowInEPSG4326,pixelValuesOfCenterPointsOfKeyWindow,centerPointsOfKeyWindowsAsGeoJSONInEPSG4326,pixelsValuesSatisfyThreshold,averageHeightsPerKeyWindow,distancesFromCenterPointsOfKeyWindowsToNearestEdge,PECTerrestrialRiskForKeyGridCellsInTreatment,ETRForPECTerrestrialForKeyGridCellsInTreatment,fieldCoordinatesAsTextInWKTInEPSG4326,selectedSiteID,threshold,visOp0,visOp1,visOp2,visOp3,_ETRRisk
    else:
        raise Exception ("WTF.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way to free up some memory could be to use the [`del` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) to explicitly "delete" an object if it is not needed anymore.

In a nutshell, it decreases the reference count for an object and when the reference count reaches 0, it gets freed.

In some extreme cases you could also try calling [`gc.collect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html?highlight=gc%20run#gc.collect), i.e. when you want to call the garbage collector manually to free some memory. But that should only be necessary in edge cases.

Comment: thanks. i placed "del params" inside the if-statement in run() beofre the return statment, but the memory is still getting occupied !!